# Нужна ли запятая в придаточном предложении, если в нём неоднородные сказуемые?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп, придаточное-предложение

> Олег остался дома, потому что был уже вечер(,) и идти никуда не
> хотелось.

Я так понимаю, здесь два неоднородных сказуемых, поэтому запятая нужна. Правильно ли я мыслю?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В любом случае это сложное предложение состоит из трёх. Их **основы:**
*Олег остался, был вечер, идти не хотелось* (безличное).

С первыми двумя частями проблем нет. Второе предложение является придаточным причины с союзом ***потому что***. Остаётся определить статус третьего.

1. *Олег остался дома, **потому что был уже вечер и идти никуда не хотелось.***

В этом случае мы имеем два однородных придаточных предложения, запятая перед ***и*** не ставится, пауза не выражена. Так обозначены две причины:
*Олег остался дома, **потому что был уже вечер.***
*Олег остался дома, **потому что идти никуда не хотелось.***

> 3. Между однородными придаточными частями сложноподчиненного предложения, связанными неповторяющимися союзами (соединительными или разделительными) запятая не ставится...

2. *Олег остался дома, **потому что был уже вечер**, и идти никуда не хотелось.*

Здесь третье предложение независимо, его можно рассматривать в качестве присоединительного с явной паузой перед ним. Если придаточное причины убрать, останется сложносочиненное предложение:

*Олег остался дома, и идти никуда не хотелось.*

Посмотрите **примечание** к пункту 3 правил, там как раз говорится о различной пунктуации в зависимости от смысла и приводится такой пример:

> *Мысль о скорой разлуке со мной так поразила матушку, **что она уронила ложку в кастрюльку**, и слёзы потекли по её лицу* (П.) — при отсутствии запятой перед ***и*** текст имел бы такой вид: *…так поразила матушку, что… слёзы потекли по её лицу.*

[Знаки препинания в сложноподчиненном предложении с несколькими придаточными](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=139) (справочник Розенталя).

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ!

Comment: @Theej Спасибо за интересный вопрос!

Answer (score 2):

Наличие запятой или отсутствие при сложносочинённой связи предложений не относит или относит предложения к единому предложению, слову, сочетанию. Чтобы это понять, взгляните на следующие примеры:

> В газетной заметке указывается, что ожидаются заморозки и следует принять меры к защите ранних овощей от холода. (В газете пишется о заморозках и даются рекомендации.)

> В газетной заметке указывается, что ожидаются заморозки, и следует принять меры к защите ранних овощей от холода. (В газете пишется только о заморозках, а рекомендации дает говорящий данное предложение.)

В предложении выше можно ставить и не ставить запятую, что будет несколько различать смыслы. В вашем же предложении — ‟Олег остался дома, потому что был уже вечер и идти никуда не хотелось” — может быть только один вариант, где запятой нет, потому что оба сложносочиненных относятся к союзу ‟потому что” и вместе составляют причину. Причина в том, что и был вечер, и идти никуда не хотелось.

Comment: Спасибо, что объяснили!